# How can I make a copy of an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a script where I create an object, and I want to make a copy of it, but when I assign the object to another variable if I change it will change both.

I've been reading a book and what I understand is that is is a reference and not a value, but I want to copy an object and treat them separately from that point. This is an example of what I do:

```
var myObject = {};
var copyOfMyObject = myObject;
myObject.foo = 'bar';

console.log(myObject, copyOfMyObject);

//logs Object {foo="bar"} Object {foo="bar"}
```

Is there a way to copy the whole object where I can change their properties independently without affecting the other?

Comment: Do you want a deep copy?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Comment: @Slaks excuse me sir I'm not sure what a deep copy means

Comment: http://blog.imaginea.com/deep-copy-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to map each property to the new array:

Simple one level clone can be made like this:

```
function clone(a, b) {
    var prop;
    for( prop in b ) {
        b[prop] = a;
    }
}
```

This will clone all properties from `b` to `a`. But keep all other properties in `a`:

```
var a = {a: 9, c: 1},
    b = {a: 1, b: 1};

copy(a, b); // {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1}
```

---

#### Deep Clone Object:

The above example will work when dealing with single level objects, but will make a confusion when multiply levels is present, take a look at this example:

```
var a = {},
    b = { a: { a: 1 } }

clone(a, b);

a.a.a = 2; 
console.log(a); // { a: { a: 2 } }
console.log(b); // { a: { a: 2 } }
```

The above example proves that the object inside `a.a` is the same as the one inside `b.a`.

Comment: +1 so after this I can manipulate my objects without affecting the other right

Comment: @iker Yes if you are working with single level objects! If you have multi level objects you will have to make a recursive function and maybe you want to take care of arrays, dates, etc aswell.